# How to Retrieve Specific table from HTML FILE in c#?

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-parsing

I have an HTML file that contains many tables, but I want to access a specific table from the file (not all tables).
So how can I do that?
Code is look something like below and all tables are without ids

```
`<table border=1>
<tr><td>VI not loadable</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>Test not loadable</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>Test not runnable</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>Test error out</td><td>0</td></tr>
</table>`
```

Answer (score 1):

every table should have an Id or something that could be Identified from the others, if so you can get it  via jquery. for example :

```
 <table class="table table-striped" id="tbl1">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>john@example.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mary</td>
    <td>Moe</td>
    <td>mary@example.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>July</td>
    <td>Dooley</td>
    <td>july@example.com</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

and get it like this:

```
var table = $('#tbl1').html();
```

if not you can find it by its priority in the file. for example you can access to 2nd table like this :

```
var table = $('table:nth-child(2)')
```

or in C# maybe this would help:

```
HtmlNode table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[1]")
foreach (var cell in table.SelectNodes(".//tr/td")) 
{
     string someVariable = cell.InnerText
}
```

Comment: the problem is file did not contain any id or class:

Comment: I think best solution is to get target table by its priority otherwise when tables do not have any indicator explain how you can recognize your desired option so that I can help you to implement a good solution.

Comment: I m using this code to get a table but it returns all tables from the file. I want to retrieve a specific table:

`foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table"))
{
    ///This is the table.    
    foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(row.OuterHtml);
        foreach (HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("th|td"))
        {
            ///This the cell.
            Console.WriteLine(html);
        }
    }
}`

Comment: I`m glad it worked, make me happy and mark it as correct answer :)